# Adding tooltip to mobile with click action using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm pretty new to this so help and possibly patience would be appreciated. I've spent a few hours trying to string together a solution based on other peoples problems but I'm struggling.

I have icons on a website that on desktop hover will show the img title as a tooltip. Unfortunately on tablet/mobile this doesn't work. I assume because we can't hover on those browsers. Example page: http://queenofretreats.com/retreat/strategic-space-burgundy-france/ - you'll see the 8 turquoise icons below the main image. These are the icons in question.

I found a solution that adds the img title on click using javascript. Solution demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bo28190/s3dg50y4/

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work on my actual wp installation.

I've added the script as a .js file in my theme folder. I've called the script from functions.php using

```
/**
 * Enqueue a script
 */
function myprefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mobile-icon-tooltip', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/mobile-icon-tooltip.js', array(), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_enqueue_scripts' );
```

I've added the jquery UI library , adding:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But the tooltip doesn't show click on any screen size.

Comment: I opened your Wordpress website and my browser got 404 error while trying to download the script - http://queenofretreats.com/wp-content/themes/onepress/js/mobile-icon-tooltip.js?ver=1.

Are you sure you added the script to the correct directory on the server?

Comment: Hi Catalyst, Thanks for your input. here is the file: http://queenofretreats.com/wp-content/themes/onepress/assets/js/mobile-icon-tooltip.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'mobile-icon-tooltip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mobile-icon-tooltip.js', array(), true );`

with this:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'mobile-icon-tooltip', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/mobile-icon-tooltip.js', array(), true );`

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns the *stylesheet* URI, while what you really want is the theme base URI.

Comment: I've replaced that now but it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Can you paste here the whole function, just like you did in your question? Something in your code doesn't seem right.

Comment: OK, so now the Javascript file loads correctly, but it seems like you didn't include jQuery UI library (in order to use the `tooltip` widget).

Comment: Progress! How would I go about adding jQuery UI library?

Comment: SO I've added jqoery UI using Google CDN